# Use value from json callback as an argument in another function

Tags: javascript, json

This is for a weather app. I am trying to take a value from a json, assign it to a variable, then use that variable as an argument in a function call inside the json callback. This works if I use a switch statement, but I'm trying to avoid that, so I constructed a function with an object and html values. When run, it should choose the right html and append it to a div.

The problem is that it only works if explicitly define the value of 'icon' in the iconPicker function. Otherwise, the alert at the end keeps giving me 'undefined'. Feel like I'm missing some basic scope problem here. Help!

```
const iconPicker = (icon) => {
  const rainy = '<div class="icon rainy"><div class="cloud"></div><div class="rain"></div></div>';
  const sunny = '<div class="icon sunny"><div class="sun"><div class="rays"></div></div></div>';
  const overcast = '<div class="icon cloudy"><div class="cloud"></div><div class="cloud"></div></div>';
  const partlySunny = '<div class="cloud"></div><div class="sun"><div class="rays"></div></div>';
  const stormy = '<div class="icon thunder-storm"><div class="cloud"></div><div class="lightning"><div class="bolt"></div><div class="bolt"></div></div></div>';
  const snowy = '<div class="icon flurries"><div class="cloud"></div><div class="snow"><div class="flake"></div><div class="flake"></div></div></div>';

  const iconObj = {
    'rain': rainy,
    'chancerain': rainy,
    'clear': sunny,
    'sunny': sunny,
    'mostlysunny': sunny,
    'fog': overcast,
    'cloudly': overcast,
    'hazy': partlySunny,
    'mostlycloudy': partlySunny,
    'partlycloudy': partlySunny,
    'partlysunny': partlySunny,
    'chancetstorms': stormy,
    'tstorms': stormy,
    'chanceflurries': snowy,
    'chancesleet': snowy,
    'chancesnow': snowy,
    'flurries': snowy,
    'sleet': snowy,
    'snow': snowy
  }
  $('.icon').append(iconObj[icon]);
  alert(iconObj[icon]);
}

const currentConditions = () => {
  let icon;
  $.getJSON('http://api.wunderground.com/api/e95fb12f6c69ae61/geolookup/conditions/q/autoip.json', function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    tempf = json.current_observation.temp_f;
    tempc = json.current_observation.temp_c;
    icon = json.current_observation.icon;
    city = json.location.city;
    country = json.location.country_name;
    $('.location').html(city + ', ' + country);
    $('.weather').html(tempf + '&deg' + '<a href=# class="scale scaleF">F</a>');
    $('.weather').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let element = $(e.target);
      if(element.hasClass('scaleF')) {
        $('.weather').html(tempc + '&deg' + '<a href=# class="scale scaleC">C</a>');
      } else if (element.hasClass('scaleC')){
        $('.weather').html(tempf + '&deg' + '<a href=# class="scale scaleF">F</a>');
      }
    });
    iconPicker(icon);
  });
};
```

Comment: Hmm. Try removing `let icon;` in the `currentConditions` scope, and add `let icon = ...` in the `getJSON` callback scope

Comment: fwiw I can not reproduce the issue. The code above works fine for me.

Comment: The code is not very elegant but it seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/rn2to99p/

Comment: Here's a pen of the whole thing with the switch statement. http://codepen.io/MAHolzbach/pen/qmdEvr Joe, it's returning a html value from the iconPicker function? I'm still getting 'undefined'.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/rjljFSbqQOzFAVSbiSXs?p=preview